# How to apply the ConvLSTM layers

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

I was doing a classification machine learning with an input of (700,50,34) (batch, step,features)

```
def convLSTM_model(X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test, num_classes,loss, batch_size=68, units=128, learning_rate=0.005,
                           epochs=20, dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.2):
    class myCallback(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):

        def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
            if (logs.get('acc') > 0.9):
                print("\nReached 90% accuracy so cancelling training!")
                self.model.stop_training = True

    callbacks = myCallback()

    model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
    model.add(Masking(mask_value=0.0, input_shape=(None,X_train.shape[0],X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2])))
    
    model.add(ConvLSTM2D(filters=40, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding="same", return_sequences=True))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())

    model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(units, dropout=dropout, recurrent_dropout=recurrent_dropout, return_sequences=True)))
    model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(units, dropout=dropout, recurrent_dropout=recurrent_dropout, return_sequences=True)))
    model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(units, dropout=dropout, recurrent_dropout=recurrent_dropout)))
    model.add(Dense(30, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(10, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))

    adamopt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=learning_rate, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-8)

    model.compile(loss=loss,
                  optimizer=adamopt,
                  metrics=['accuracy'])

    history = model.fit(X_train, y_train,
                        batch_size=batch_size,
                        epochs=epochs,
                        validation_data=(X_test, y_test),
                        verbose=1,
                        callbacks=[callbacks])

    score, acc = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test,
                                batch_size=batch_size)

    yhat = model.predict(X_test)

    return history, that
```

Apparently, changing the input_shape and simply adding

```
model.add(ConvLSTM2D(filters=40, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding="same", return_sequences=True))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
```

does not work.

```
ValueError: Dimension 1 in both shapes must be equal, but are 708 and 501264. Shapes are [?,708,50,40] and [?,501264,2500,40]. for 'conv_lst_m2d/while/Select' (op: 'Select') with input shapes: [?,501264,2500,40], [?,708,50,40], [?,708,50,40].
```

How should I approach?
Is there any suggestion on the number of filter?

Comment: What is your input data here? and am I correct in understanding that you have 34 features(time dependent) which you want to use 50(timesteps) at a time?

Comment: Yes, so without the ConvLSTM layer, my code for input shape was ```model.add(Masking(mask_value=0.0, input_shape=(X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2])))```

Comment: There might be a problem here with the input dimension. As per what I see [on](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/ConvLSTM2D) tensorflow site, the input tensor has to be 5D. Another issue could be that convLSTM layer may need the mask explicitly(just a possibility), refer [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/masking_and_padding?hl=en#mask_propagation_in_the_functional_api_and_sequential_api)

Comment: @sai Exactly, the info provided on the site is limited. I hope if there is someone who knows how to apply it to my case.

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? Your data just don´t has the shape for LSTMConv2D. You are missing channels and rows. Channels can be 1, but row must be a real dimension. Otherwise LSTMConv2D is just not the Layer you need to use.
What do you want to convolute? LSTMConv2D is typically used for Machine Learning with Videos (3D arrays over time --> 4D).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one, I believe the `CNN` layer should be implemented before the `masking` layer.

```
    model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
    
    model.add(Conv1D(filters=32, kernel_size=8, strides=1, activation="relu", padding="same",input_shape=(X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2])))
    model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size = 2))
    model.add(Conv1D(filters=16, kernel_size=8, strides=1, activation="relu", padding="same"))
    model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size = 2))
    
    
    model.add(Masking(mask_value=0.0))
    model.add(LSTM(units, dropout=dropout, recurrent_dropout=recurrent_dropout, return_sequences=True))
    model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(units, dropout=dropout, recurrent_dropout=recurrent_dropout, return_sequences=True)))
    model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(units, dropout=dropout, recurrent_dropout=recurrent_dropout, return_sequences=True)))
    model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(units, dropout=dropout, recurrent_dropout=recurrent_dropout)))
    model.add(Dense(30, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(10, activation='relu'))
    
    model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))
```

Answer (score 1):

I now tried to use your code. You will get better anwers at stackoverflow when you supply a minimum working example. I build some test data with the same shape that you used.

When usind an LSTMConv2D I could reproduce your problem. But since your Data just doesn´t fit to the Conv2D Layer and substituted this with a normal LSTM Layer.
If instead you want to convolute the timestep I would suggest using an CONV1D Layer first and LSTM afterwards.

Minimum working example:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Masking, ConvLSTM2D, LSTM, Bidirectional, Dense
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers.normalization_v2 import BatchNormalization

batch_size=68
units=128
learning_rate=0.005
epochs=20
dropout=0.2
recurrent_dropout=0.2
X_train = np.random.rand(700, 50,34)
y_train = np.random.choice([0, 1], 700)
X_test = np.random.rand(100, 50, 34)
y_test = np.random.choice([0, 1], 100)
loss = tf.losses.binary_crossentropy

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(Masking(mask_value=0.0, input_shape=(X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2])))
# uncomment the line beneath for convolution
# model.add(Conv1D(filters=32, kernel_size=8, strides=1, activation="relu", padding="same"))
model.add(LSTM(units, dropout=dropout, recurrent_dropout=recurrent_dropout, return_sequences=True))
model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(units, dropout=dropout, recurrent_dropout=recurrent_dropout, return_sequences=True)))
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(units, dropout=dropout, recurrent_dropout=recurrent_dropout, return_sequences=True)))
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(units, dropout=dropout, recurrent_dropout=recurrent_dropout)))
model.add(Dense(30, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(10, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

adamopt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=learning_rate, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-8)

model.compile(loss=loss,
              optimizer=adamopt,
              metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(X_train, y_train,
                    batch_size=batch_size,
                    epochs=epochs,
                    validation_data=(X_test, y_test),
                    verbose=1)

score, acc = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test,
                            batch_size=batch_size)

yhat = model.predict(X_test)
```

Comment: OK, I am not sure Conv2D is exactly what I am looking for. What I am trying to achieve is to train a model that involves features from both time domain and frequency domain. So for time domain, using RNN such as LSTM is reasonable but for other features, I thought using CNN for such dataset may improve the accuracy. I am not good at CNN, so I wonder if there is a way to include CNN into the model.  Would you mind to write in CNN layers in your codes?

Comment: Hey Leo, 
I edited my answer and added a Line for a Conv1D Layer. It convoluts the timesteps. You may also have a look at WaveEncoders. 
1-dimensional Convolution is the right choice for you instead of 2D since you have a 1D feature array per sample instead of a 2D feature array (like a picture).

Comment: TypeError: Layer conv1d does not support masking, but was passed an input_mask: Tensor("masking/Squeeze:0", shape=(?, 50), dtype=bool)